# asp.net mvc multiple table join with groupby clause returning duplicates

Tags: linq, entity-framework, join, group-by, linq-to-entities

I am fetching data from multiple tables using joins and one o the table image is attached below which is causing issue. This table keeps track of status of tests, i want tests that have process id 11 but as its tracking table multiple rows reutrning which is causing repeating of one record three times in my view i am trying to aplly groupby on bookingdid and get the max trackid which is unique identity of table but i am unable to do that my linq query is also below. any help.

[image: dc_tstatustrack table]

here is my linq query:

```
using (var db = new bc_limsEntities())
            {
                var result = (from d in db.dc_tpatient_bookingd
                              join m in db.dc_tpatient_bookingm on d.bookingid equals m.bookingid into a
                              from m in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              join p in db.dc_tpatient on m.prid equals p.prid into b
                              from p in b.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              join t in db.dc_tp_test on d.testid equals t.TestId into c
                              from t in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              //join mt in db.dc_tp_tmethod on t.TestId equals mt.testid into j
                              //from mt in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              // join gm in db.dc_tp_groupm on t.GroupId equals gm.GroupId into e
                              //from gm in e.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              join pn in db.dc_tpanel on m.panelid equals pn.panelid into f
                              from pn in f.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              join og in db.dc_tp_organization on m.clientid equals og.OrgId into g
                              from og in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              join w in db.dc_tp_ward on m.wardid equals w.wardid into h
                              from w in h.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              join tb in db.dc_tp_branch on m.BranchID equals tb.BranchID into i
                              from tb in i.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              join bd in db.dc_tp_refdoctors on m.doctorid equals bd.doctorid into k
                              from bd in k.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              join dt in db.dc_tstatustrack on d.bookingdid equals dt.bookingdid into l
                              from dt in l.DefaultIfEmpty()







                              where d.ProcessID == 5


                              && t.SubdepartmentId == subDepartmentID








                                  && fromDate <= m.enteredon && m.enteredon <= DateTime.Now

                                  && d.status != "H"

                                  && DateTime.Now > d.deliverytime

                                  && dt.processid == 11




                              select new { d, p, m, t, bd, pn, dt }).Distinct().ToList();
```

I did something like this but not worked for me:

```
group new { d, p, m, t, bd, pn, dt } by new { dt.bookingdid } into mno
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: did you try: group  dt  by  dt.bookingdid  into mno

Comment: i did but i am not getting how to iterate on rows after that for getting data